# Shipping discount based on cart weight

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

very new to Shopify and I am slowly taking over the stores at my new job.

One thing we are trying to achieve is to be able to define rules that would either create discount codes or directly apply discounted rates based on the car weight.

This would be super straight forward in the world I come from of making my own web/mobile apps, but I would like some guidance as to how do i achieve this in Shopify. Is making a custom app the way to go?

If so, how can that augment the checkout page when the user is about to make a purchase?

I am now just going through the custom app development (QR code app) but I would like to know already if that is even the way to go about it.

Currently the only attempt made is using the "Script Editor" app to generate static discount codes like so:

```
{
    customer_tag_match_type: :include,
    customer_tags: ["SH123FREE"],
    rate_match_type: :exact,
    rate_names: ["EMS International Express",
    "By-Expressen - levering med bybud",
    "DHL Domestic Express (1 business day)",
    "DHL Economy EU (2-5 business days)",
    "DHL Economy (2-4 business days)",
    "DSV XPress Economy (6-10 business days)",
    "DSV XPress Economy (3-4 business days)",
    "DSV XPress USA (6-10 business days)"],
    discount_type: :percent,
    discount_amount: 100,
    discount_message: "Free shipping applied"
  },
  {
    customer_tag_match_type: :include,
    customer_tags: ["SH12350_OFF"],
    rate_match_type: :exact,
    rate_names: ["EMS International Express",
    "By-Expressen - levering med bybud",
    "DHL Domestic Express (1 business day)",
    "DHL Economy EU (2-5 business days)",
    "DHL Economy (2-4 business days)",
    "DSV XPress Economy (6-10 business days)",
    "DSV XPress Economy (3-4 business days)",
    "DSV XPress Economy USA (6-10 business days)"],
    discount_type: :percent,
    discount_amount: 50,
    discount_message: "50% off shipping applied"
  }
```

But obviously this is just static and is not based on cart weight.

I was actually thinking that I could create a simple service that I could deploy on AWS lamba and when people load the checkout page, it could pass the cart details / weight and get back and apply a discount code that I have statically pre-generated as shown above.

I am just not sure this is possible though within Shopify?

I'd love any help or pointers in the right direction :)

We have currently started creating static discount codes to give wholesale partners they can manually add in the system.

In parallel I starting to look at doing custom apps in order to see if this is the way to go to achieve our goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the script editor you can apply a discount based on total cart weight which is in grams:

```
class Campaign
  def initialize(condition, *qualifiers)
    @condition = (condition.to_s + '?').to_sym
    @qualifiers = PostCartAmountQualifier ? [] : [] rescue qualifiers.compact
    @line_item_selector = qualifiers.last unless @line_item_selector
    qualifiers.compact.each do |qualifier|
      is_multi_select = qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).is_a?(Array)
      if is_multi_select
        qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).each do |nested_q|
          @post_amount_qualifier = nested_q if nested_q.is_a?(PostCartAmountQualifier)
          @qualifiers << qualifier
        end
      else
        @post_amount_qualifier = qualifier if qualifier.is_a?(PostCartAmountQualifier)
        @qualifiers << qualifier
      end
    end if @qualifiers.empty?
  end

  def qualifies?(cart)
    return true if @qualifiers.empty?
    @unmodified_line_items = cart.line_items.map do |item|
      new_item = item.dup
      new_item.instance_variables.each do |var|
        val = item.instance_variable_get(var)
        new_item.instance_variable_set(var, val.dup) if val.respond_to?(:dup)
      end
      new_item
    end if @post_amount_qualifier
    @qualifiers.send(@condition) do |qualifier|
      is_selector = false
      if qualifier.is_a?(Selector) || qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).any? { |q| q.is_a?(Selector) }
        is_selector = true
      end rescue nil
      if is_selector
        raise "Missing line item match type" if @li_match_type.nil?
        cart.line_items.send(@li_match_type) { |item| qualifier.match?(item) }
      else
        qualifier.match?(cart, @line_item_selector)
      end
    end
  end

  def run_with_hooks(cart)
    before_run(cart) if respond_to?(:before_run)
    run(cart)
    after_run(cart)
  end

  def after_run(cart)
    @discount.apply_final_discount if @discount && @discount.respond_to?(:apply_final_discount)
    revert_changes(cart) unless @post_amount_qualifier.nil? || @post_amount_qualifier.match?(cart)
  end

  def revert_changes(cart)
    cart.instance_variable_set(:@line_items, @unmodified_line_items)
  end
end

class ShippingDiscount < Campaign
  def initialize(condition, customer_qualifier, cart_qualifier, li_match_type, line_item_qualifier, rate_selector, discount)
    super(condition, customer_qualifier, cart_qualifier, line_item_qualifier)
    @li_match_type = (li_match_type.to_s + '?').to_sym
    @rate_selector = rate_selector
    @discount = discount
  end

  def run(rates, cart)
    raise "Campaign requires a discount" unless @discount
    return unless qualifies?(cart)
    rates.each do |rate|
      next unless @rate_selector.nil? || @rate_selector.match?(rate)
      @discount.apply(rate)
    end
  end
end

class Selector
  def partial_match(match_type, item_info, possible_matches)
    match_type = (match_type.to_s + '?').to_sym
    if item_info.kind_of?(Array)
      possible_matches.any? do |possibility|
        item_info.any? do |search|
          search.send(match_type, possibility)
        end
      end
    else
      possible_matches.any? do |possibility|
        item_info.send(match_type, possibility)
      end
    end
  end
end

class RateNameSelector < Selector
  def initialize(match_type, match_condition, names)
    @match_condition = match_condition
    @invert = match_type == :does_not
    @names = names.map(&:downcase)
  end

  def match?(shipping_rate)
    name = shipping_rate.name.downcase
    case @match_condition
      when :match
        return @invert ^ @names.include?(name)
      else
        return @invert ^ partial_match(@match_condition, name, @names)
    end
  end
end

class PercentageDiscount
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Decimal.new(percent) / 100
    @message = message
  end

  def apply(rate)
    rate.apply_discount(rate.price * @percent, { message: @message })
  end
end

# discount based on cart weight
discount = Input.cart.total_weight * 0.1


CAMPAIGNS = [
  ShippingDiscount.new(
    :all,
    nil,
    nil,
    :any,
    nil,
    RateNameSelector.new(
      :does,
      :start_with,
      ["Standard Shipping"]
    ),
    PercentageDiscount.new(
      discount,
      "Weight Discount"
    )
  )
].freeze

CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.shipping_rates, Input.cart)
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

In this case, 100 grams = 10% discount. A discount will be applied if the shipping name starts from Standard Shipping. Note that products without set weight won't be taken into account.

Comment: Also, you can rewrite that bloated script to be < 10 lines of Ruby, ensuring it runs fast, uses less memory, and perhaps is just easier to maintain. These scripts copy and pasted from Shopify leave a lot to be desired as they are grossly over-engineered and often fail due to their size and slowness.

Comment: @DavidLazar I'm afraid I have to disagree - This is a campaign builder pattern that works great if you have many campaigns running in the same script or helps to make any example quickly. This one took me 3 minutes to create including testing. This example looks scary but scales well if you have many campaigns. Regarding memory and CPU it's not a concern either because this script does not use any algorithms that would require any notable amount of space and time. If the character limit is a concern, you can minify classes. You don't touch them ever any way.

Comment: Note that Shopify assigns RAM and CPU amounts based on the cart size so it works proportionally. We had way more complex scripts running and never had an issue

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! I appreciate it :) Is script editor the only way to go about it? Aren't custom apps a possibility? or having the cart / checkout ping an api and potentially add a pre-made discount? I am new to Shopify and I find Ruby incredibly off-putting and would rather find a JS way of doing this. It's quite a mouthful to look at this and trying understanding this in a language im unfamiliar with :/

Comment: If you find Ruby off-putting compared to Javascript, that is analog to saying calculus is harder than adding 2 + 2 in your head hehehe. Anyway, lucky for you, scripting in Ruby is as easy or easier than JS any day of the week, and if you can do JS you can 100% do Ruby. Almost all scripting languages are basically compatible with each other...

Comment: @TwistedOwl, my comment was just directly addressing this issue. While that script may work for your needs, in the case of just needing to alter one thing, you do not need the complexity and overhead. While I understand where you are coming from, my point stands. Using 10 lines of code instead of 100 can often be smarter. If you really need the 100, so be it.

Comment: @DavidLazar how does the 10 lines example look like then? :D

Comment: Depends. It is not my job to actually write them here. I am just commenting that the copy paste example is bloated. Nothing more, nothing less.